# how do I get the tag name from tag id?

Tags: tags

I have the tag ID, in integer format.

I want to convert this to the tag name.  e.g. "cars"

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`get_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag).

```
$tag = get_tag(2); // <-- your tag ID
echo $tag->name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally, a simple answer... everywhere else was trying to make things waaaaay too complicated. Just wanted exactly what you gave me - a way to plugin in a tag id and get its name.